# Has Biden taken any action to reform the Supreme Court?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, joe-biden

President Biden established [The Presidential Commission on the Supreme Court of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Commission_on_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States#Report) to investigate ideas for reform of the Supreme Court. The commission first sat on May 19, 2021 and issued its final [report](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/SCOTUS-Report-Final-12.8.21-1.pdf) on December 8, 2021. I haven't been able to find out if any action have been taken, as a result of this report, with a view to reforming the Supreme Court.  The Wikipedia page is out of date and has a request for updates dated November 2021.

Has Biden taken any actions resulting from this report?

Comment: Simple answer: no, and he says he has currently no plans to.  Realistically we are way too close to the midterms for anything to happen (and also there's a very good chance republicans take the Senate, so the last thing they would want to do is gut the filibuster only to hand the keys over)

Comment: @eps  That sounds like it would make a good answer.  Do you know where Biden said he didn't have any plans to do anything?